# How to create cue-sheet for long WAV file?

Tags: audio, wav

I have a big WAV file that contains a set of a bunch of songs mixed together.

Is there a way I could define "bookmarks" or cue-splits so I can play that cue and have each track separated (pointing to a specific time in the WAV file) or something like that?

Comment: How do you intend to playback this wav file? Using any specific software?

Comment: Right now I'm using AIMP3, but I could use another if it's free and lightweight.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but what I do in these situations is use Audacity or other tool to automatically split into individual songs.

Comment: @DrMayhem Thanks, but I don't want to split it, I just want to "mark" it.

Comment: "Rekordbox" is free Pioneer software designed to organise songs for Pioneer hardware (I.e setting cue points, memory locations, playlists). But I don't know whether it will suit your application. Its not suitable to play live because you can't mix in a second song. I believe it has 10 memory slots for each song.

Comment: Is there a reason your songs are "smashed together" instead of being separate files?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Sure, it's a DJ set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it really is all a matter of what you're using to playback the .wav file. What you need is a player that supports .cue files directly. One such free player I found is clementine-player, however I haven't personally tried it.

Make a text file in notepad named the same as your .wav file, but name it .cue

The text(cue) file should be like this:

```
TRACK 01 AUDIO
   TITLE "Whatever you call the first track"
   PERFORMER "I don't think you have to include this"
   INDEX 01 00:00:00
 TRACK 02 AUDIO
   TITLE "Second Track PT 1"
   PERFORMER "Whoever"
   INDEX 00 02:47:74
   INDEX 01 02:48:27
 TRACK 03 AUDIO
   TITLE "3rd"
   PERFORMER "You guys"
   INDEX 00 02:48:27
   INDEX 01 04:00:15
```

and so on... notice that the important parts are the index points- everyone but the first gets 2; INDEX 00 and INDEX 01. INDEX 00 is going to be the end point, or "INDEX 01" of the previous track. INDEX 01 will, of course, be the endpoint of the current track. (Not to mention the INDEX 00 of the NEXT track).

The audio player should read the cue file directly and give you your cue points. Not the easiest way of going about it, but it's what you asked for. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add markers (usually both index markers and region markers) to a wave files using audio editors such as Adobe Audition or Sony Sound Forge. As long as you stay in such a software application, you can jump to markers or playback a region as a loop very easily using shortcuts or GUI.

When the wave file is saved, markers are stored into the file as metadata which are not always compatible with other software applications. And I never saw a simple media player providing a way to exploit these metadata.

Another idea would be to use a DJ software application, like Traktor (charged and proprietary) or Mixxx (free and open source). In this case, the markers information may be store in an embedded database instead of the file itself.